# Setup DNS for my server which is using static IP that can be access from anywhere on the internet

Tags: networking, dns, ip, static-ip

I have setup a static IP from my internet provider so that any one on the internet can access content on my server.

I want to setup domain's to redirect to my server and load web site from my server which is located in our office premises.

From what I understand, for this I have to set the DNS entry for the domain.

How should I set this entry which is generally in for form of **cp-30.webxxxbox.net** and **cp-32.webxxxbox.net**.

Is it possible to generate such entries for my server which is powered by Ubuntu?

Thank you,

Yogesh

Comment: Speak to your ISP. They will be able to advise you.

Comment: Who did you purchase your domain  name from?   Usually the company your purchase your domain name from will have some interface that allows you to point the public named DNS record to your static IP address given to you by your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track when it comes to setting up the DNS server, but there's a little more to it:

First you need to set up your domain names so that it points to a specified DNS server. Wherever you registered the domain name should be your go-to place for this.

As for the DNS server you specified, it mainly needs two things:
An [NS-record](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/ns-record/), and an [A-record](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/a-record/). The NS record basically defines one or more DNS servers for your domain. The A-record is what resolves the actual hostname(s) belonging to the domain.

Once you have your DNS server associated with the domain, in addition to the NS and the A record(s), your webserver should work, provided that it is configured to serve requests passed to the domain name.

I would provide configuration examples, but that would be beyond the scope of this answer, as I do not know anything about your system.

---

PS: Many domain sellers offer a DNS service. If you need a fairly basic DNS setup, you might want to talk to them about this.